# opencv cutting out letters from image with much noise (java)

Tags: java, opencv, crop

i have the following picture of which i want to crop out all letters in to new images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF6nI.jpg

The result of each letter should look like this for example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih3wL.jpg

I have had troubles achieving this, i have used thresholding, findContours, and many other things. I just cannot seem to cut out the letters since the image contains very much noise.

Can someone please provide some help and information?

Comment: You have posted way too much code for your problem. It would be better to create a simple example that reproduces your problem. What line does the error occur on? The assertion failure you see indicates that you are creating a region of interest with some corner outside the border of your image. I suspect your problem lies in defining the bounds of `rect_min`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it did not find any contours in your img, rect_min will contain invalid negative numbers, and submat will crash.

you'll have to add some logic, that cares for that.